# Decrypt .ini, and use values?

Tags: c++, encryption

I have a XOR function:

```
string encryptDecrypt(string toEncrypt) {
char key[64] = { 'F', '2', 'D', 'C', '5', '4', '0', 'D', 'B', 'F', '3', 'E', '1', '2', '9', 'F', '4', 'E', 'A', 'A', 'F', '7', '6', '7', '5', '6', '9', 'E', '3', 'C', 'F', '9', '7', '5', '2', 'B', '4', 'B', '8', '2', '6', 'D', '9', '8', 'F', 'D', '8', '3', '8', '4', '6', '0', '8', '5', 'C', '0', '3', '7', 'D', '3', '5', 'F', '7', '5' };
string output = toEncrypt;
for (int i = 0; i < toEncrypt.size(); i++)
    output[i] = toEncrypt[i] ^ key[i % (sizeof(key) / sizeof(char))];
return output;
```

}

I encrypted my .ini :

```
[test]
baubau = 1
haha = 2
sometext = blabla
```

How i tried to decrypt and use values:

```
std::string Filename = "abc.ini";
std::ifstream input(Filename, std::ios::binary | ios::in);  // Open the file
std::string line;                                           // Temp variable
std::vector<std::string> lines;                             // Vector for holding all lines in the file
while (std::getline(input, line))                           // Read lines as long as the file is
{
lines.push_back(encryptDecrypt(line));
}
// Here i should call the ini reader? but how?
CIniReader iniReader("abc.ini");
string my = encryptDecrypt(iniReader.ReadString("test", "baubau", ""));
for (auto s : lines)   
{
    cout << my;
    cout << endl;                                        
}
```

Where is my mistake? Some help would be apreciated, Many Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure your cout for your output is what you want. I mean you have a for loop where you do not use the string s but print whatever was from the decryption text each loop.

Comment: Yes, well i use cout to see if it does decrypt it, well my code is wrong...

Comment: Tell us what results you got that differed from what you expected.

Comment: I dont get any... when trying to get from .ini it does not output almost anything... that`s the problem

Comment: Maybe the .ini file was never read because its in the wrong folder. Remember the default folder in Visual Studio is the folder containing the project file not the executable (unless you changed that). I would start at making sure you are actually reading data from the ini file. And use the debugger.

Comment: The .ini is read, but it`s not decrypted/read the right way, i need to read the entire .ini, the be able to use the values...

Comment: ***Where is my mistake?*** You are not using your debugger. If the ini file was read correctly I would expect my to have a value.

Comment: You don`t understand me, i don`t know how to decrypt the whole file....

Comment: Are you encrypting the entire file, and then having CIniReader look for "test" and "baubau" among the (entirely) encrypted content? It's unclear if that is your intention, but that certainly cannot work. CIniReader needs to see "test" and "baubau" in the clear, for example.

Comment: Exactly, that`s why i am here, i don`t know how to do it... please help

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is:

1. Read the file line by line, and break apart keys and values, i.e. where you see 'key=value' break it apart into key and value.
2. Encrypt the value.
3. Base64-encode the value, in case it is no longer valid text in the encoding of the file.
4. Replace the line with 'key=base64-encoded-value'.
5. Later, when you read the encoded value for the key, which is just a simple Base64-encoded string of bytes, Base64-decode the string, and the decrypt the value.

For example, this line:

baubau = 1

Take the value '1' as a string, and encrypt it with your function. The result in this case is a printable string 'w'. However, I would treat it as arbitrary bytes.

Base64-encode the "encrypted" value. For example, the Base64-encoding of 'w' in UTF-8 (or ASCII) is "dw==".

Replace the line with:

baubau = dw==

or, if you like:

baubau = "dw=="

Later, when you read the value for baubau, you simply Base64-decode 'dw==', obtaining 'w', and then decrypt 'w' to arrive at '1'.